# Wordpress posting to a password protected directory and a public blog

Tags: wordpress, passwords

I would like to use Wordpress to store all my photos and documents as an asset management system but in a secure folder that I password protect.  I would like to post the images I store there so I can see thumbnails.  I can password protect the Directory "assets" using Cpanel.

But I would also like to publish a blog that the public can view normally on my website.

So it would be as follows:

mywebsite.com/assets  (password protected)

mywebsite.com/blog  (public)

Should I do two installations of Wordpress?  Or how do I install it in one directory and I think use Categories to post?  or would this then not password protect the assets?

Answer (score 0):

You may jst set up one site
and in the wordpress theme, 
set category 'hidden' for protected files. and use php code to check if its hidden for current user before displaying

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to do that PHP code,but I'm not sure if this solves the problem, if it is hidden can it still be viewed  with a password?